# create a picture shape from an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, image, shapes

I am trying to find an example, or documentation, on creating a picture (floating shape object) inside the Excel sheet. The source is supposed to be a numeric **bitmap** data, stored in a VBA array acquired using external I/O libraries. Using Excel cells as an intermediary storage is possible, but not desired, since the RGB bitmap data is expected to be huge.
The task itself seems to be extremely simple in matlab-like environments, or python. But I just have no Idea how to make it in Excel and VBA without importing an independent image file from the file system.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?179314-Image-Editing-in-memory&s=

Answer (score 1):

In terms of storing the file, how huge is 'huge'? If you convert the image into Base64, it'll be a fairly trivial task to split it up amongst the cells and then reconstitute it when converting it into an image.

Alternatively, you can store the Base64 string in a standard module - I'm currently doing much the same thing, but my image only clocks in at 100kb (better to save it as a PNG rather than BMP).

In terms of converting the Base64 string to an image, the Windows Image Acquisition COM object will convert a byte array into a stdPicture image type (and further to my point above, it will also accept PNG files...]. The following function accepts a Base64 string, converts it into a byte array, and returns an stdPicture object:

```
Function Base64toStdPicture(ByVal Base64Code As String) As StdPicture
    
    Dim ImgVector As Object
    Dim Node      As Object
        
    Set ImgVector = CreateObject("WIA.Vector")
    Set Node = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0").createElement("base64")
        
    Node.DataType = "bin.base64"
    Node.Text = Base64Code
    ImgVector.BinaryData = Node.nodeTypedValue
    Set Base64toStdPicture = ImgVector.BinaryData.Picture
        
    Set Node = Nothing
    Set ImgVector = Nothing

End Function
```

From that point, you can out it in an image control, or copy it to / from the clipboard, etc.

Comment: interesting starter. actually, base64 is not what I have. I have (didn't get it yet actually, but according to the specs) 2 options, either 24bit RGB, or a decimal CSV stream of RGB values. I guess, bin.base64 is the particular XML-DOM property for interpretting base64. I may be very bad in searching msdn; Is there any other than base64 decoder available off the shelf?

Comment: ... and well...
Under "image control" you probably mean ActiveX userform image_control; which I particularly try to avoid. The "maximum programme" is geting the image allocated in the worksheet for the user easily picking it up as standard Office object.

Comment: Ahh, well the RGB values point might actually make things unexpectedly easier - you can read and write RGB values direct into the WIA.Vector object.

Comment: As for the image control point, that is indeed what I meant, but it's not a problem..  you could either (1) save the resulting stdPicture as image file in a temp directory and then add it to the worksheet  as a picture/shape; or, (2) prior to the conversion to an stdPicture, the image takes the form of a bitmap in memory - this can be saved to the clipboard with the SetClipboardData Win32 API and then it's just a matter of pasting the image to the worksheet.  What do you think?